# Where can I find a 90 degree splicer for #2 wire?

Tags: wiring, connectors, splices

I'm wondering if anyone makes 90 deg connector for #2 wire, in my cade Aluminum THHN? Something like this:https://www.morrisproducts.com/pc_product_detail.asp?key=272FE6C8CABC4B35A79F44E287D7E943

I don't think Morris makes it in a 90 deg, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: I doubt it... is this splice happening inside a main or subpanel? Or in a junction box somewhere? Reason I ask is, if you need that, the box may be too cramped for the splice.

Comment: I don't know a lot about this, but would one of the ["one side entry" splices](https://www.morrisproducts.com/pc_product_detail.asp?key=0F3E7DF68A2D4DA895964F9C6C2D1848) work for this?  Bending the resultant splice to 90' would be a lot easier and more compact than the one you linked (but still not 90 degrees, exactly).

Comment: Do you have room for a 90 degrees elbow connected to this splice hardware?

Answer (score 3):

Note those are 2 wires from the same direction commonly used in motors
Where the power comes in and connects to the stator in a tight space

The way professionals create a “tight 90” in this case is by crimping lugs on then bolting the 2 wires at the angle needed then insulating.

the downside to this method is the cost 2 lugs, cambric /2520 And liner-less /130  are normally used with regular tape it gets a bit expensive but you can make a 90 this way.
I don’t think I have ever seen a inline 90 degree splice.

Because of code requirements for box fill / sizing they would rarely be used so the cost would be high and we would just bolt the lugs together and insulate with tape as mentioned vs paying a high price so the DIY market would be the only use and in reality this is tiny in the electrical world.

Comment: I was just curious. When running wire through an LB it seemed like that would be an easy way to make the 90 deg turn. As it turned out it wasn't too bad.

Comment: Fittings have a cubic inch rating if the fill rating of the conduit is not exceeding the max fill a bend is much netter than creating a splice.